# Using std::system_category() in static class destructor with msvc11

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, std-system-error

I'm pretty new to C++, but I want to make sure I'm not doing something wrong here before reporting a bug to Microsoft.

Here's some sample code:

```
#include <system_error>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    ~Test()
    {
        throw system_error(5, system_category());
    }
};

Test test;

void testfunc()
{
    throw system_error(5, system_category());
}

void main()
{
    try
    {
        testfunc();
    }
    catch ( const system_error& e)
    {
    }
}
```

Now, I would expect Windows to say "the runtime has requested the program to exit in an unexpected way". However, I get a "pure virtual function called" error instead. With a little debugging, I noticed that when the static class destructor gets the `std::system_category` reference, the `::name` and `::message` members are pure virtual. However, when it is constructed in `testfunc()`, those vtable pointers are to valid functions.

My question is, am I doing something wrong by constructing my `system_error` exceptions this way? I had some code that was basically doing `throw system_error(GetLastError(), system_category());`. This happened to execute in a static destructor, and I got the pure virtual function called error.

To throw exceptions from Windows' `GetLastError()` function, should I be constructing my exceptions a different way, or is this a bug in msvc11's C++ runtime?

**EDIT**

There's been a bit of confusion about my question. My actual code is more complicated than this example, and I actually didn't expect that one of my destructors could throw. My destructor **must** call a function that could possibly throw. If I change my code to:

```
~Test()
{
    try
    {
        callSomeFuncThatCouldThrow();
    }
    catch ( … ) { }
}
```

I will *still* get the pure virtual function call error. This is because when the system_error is constructed (in `callSOmeFuncThatCouldThrow()`) it tries to use the `::message` member of the `system_category` I'm giving it, which causes the error.

Comment: Why would you want a destructor to throw in the first place? (If you're that new to C++, you may not know yet – destructors that throw are Very Bad Things.) What are you trying to accomplish? See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166663)

Comment: So I don't necessarily want it to throw. In my code my "Test" class is holding a vector<MySpecialContext *>. The MySpecialContext class is the one that has this kind of destructor. My code has a way to "clean up" one of these MySpecialContext classes. In that case, I would want the exception to bubble up. MySpecialContext holds on to some operating system resources that don't clean up very nicely on program termination. However, if my "Test" class that has the vector is destroyed during program termination and there's still a Context, it could possibly throw.

Comment: Also to follow up, I have changed my code around a bit so those exceptions will never bubble up past the destructor. I was just very surprised to see system_category have pure virtual methods (but only when it's constructed in a static class destructor), and I wanted to know if I should contact Microsoft about it.

Comment: I updated my post with more information. I might have had a little of the "what is the XY problem" going, but there's still an issue.

Comment: Please open a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) and reply here with a link to the bug so people can find it.  A minimal repro is as follows:  `#include <system_error>`  `struct C { ~C() { std::system_category().name(); } }; C x; int main() { }`.  No `throw` required.  (Alternatively, if you would prefer not to open a bug, let me know and I will be sure one gets filed.  It's up to you.)

Comment: Thanks James. I've posted it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/765636/std-error-category-destroyed-before-static-destructors-causing-pure-function-calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a Microsoft bug. `std::error_category` is an abstract base class for various unnamed types, one of which is the type returned by `system_category()`. There's one object of that type, and all calls to `system_category()` return a reference to that object. What you're seeing looks like that object is being destroyed before the destructor of the `test` object runs. If you want to satisfy the purists, change your destructor to:

```
Test::~Test() {
    const std::error_category& cat = std::system_category();
    std::cout << cat.name() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Writing to `std::cout` after `main` terminates isn't going to work much better. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn - it's required to work. There's machinery in the standard library implementation to assure that it does.

Comment: Ah, apologies, you're absolutely correct. (C++11 §27.4.1/2 for the curious.)

Comment: Posted as a bug on Connect. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the Visual C++ Standard Library implementation.  The global error category objects are implemented using static data members of a class template.  Unfortunately, within a single translation unit (a.k.a. source file), these data members will be initialized *after* all other namespace-scope objects in the translation unit and will be destroyed *before* those objects (because destruction occurs in reverse order of initialization).

My recommendation would be to avoid calling `generic_category()`, `iostream_category()`, or `system_category()` during initialization and termination (i.e., before all static objects have been initialized or after destruction of static objects has begun).

If this is not possible, the following workaround *may* work.  It's worked in the few simple tests I've run, but I can't make any guarantees about its behavior in all cases (this isn't an "official" workaround; it's just a potential workaround).  Add a .cpp file to your project with these contents:

```
// This is a workaround for a bug in the Visual C++ 2012 implementation of the
// global error category objects--generic_category(), iostream_category(), and
// system_category().
#ifdef _MSC_VER

#if _MSC_VER != 1700
#  error Please verify that this fix is still required and is still correct!
#endif

#include <system_error>

// Ensure that static objects in this translation unit get initialized "first":
#pragma warning(suppress: 4073)
#pragma init_seg(lib)

// Explicitly instantiate the global error objects in this translation unit:
template struct std::_Error_objects<int>;

#endif // _MSC_VER
```

The `#pragma init_seg(lib)` should ensure that static data members of `_Error_objects<int>` will be initialized before any static objects in user code.  Do not put anything else in this source file:  the `#pragma init_seg` applies to all objects in the translation unit.  `_Error_objects` is an implementation detail, and that implementation detail may change at any time, hence the compiler version checks.